# C# Win32 Fire event on file read

Tags: c#, file, winapi

I want to be able to detect if a file is read by another process. For example, if a text editor open's a file, I want to have a function to be able to get the name of the file that was read.

I saw that you can use the `FileSystemWatcher` class in C# to watch a directory for file changes but they don't solve the problem, I saw these on a 6 year old thread.

Has anything new been added to C# or Win32's API since then to allow file open detection?

Comment: If the file is a DLL the following might help: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656

Comment: @EJoshuaS The files can be any format, thanks though.

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't help you much then. I wasn't sure, that's why I put it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: So, to be clear, you have a specific set of files and you want to know *when* one of these files starts being read and *which one*, and that's the limit of what you need? If so, you might be able to use Win32 OpLocks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, I know exactly which files I need to watch. And yes, all I need to know is what file. I'll check it out, thanks

Comment: Here's an [Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130415-00/?p=4663) post where Raymond shows a small code sample.

Comment: Sounds like a file is the wrong thing to use here because anything can read a file. Perhaps you need something where you control the interface and access to the content. Spying on all file access sounds rather like malware though. I expect AV tools would have the same viewpoint.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure how that would work to do what I want. I'm trying to make a FTP system where you traverse your local drive to a file and it fetches the respective remote file from the FTP server. I guess I could just set up manual fetching and then upload when the program detects the file has been changed.

Comment: OK, that's never going to work the way you imagine it.  You need a namespace extension or something along those lines. You should ask about your problem not about your solution. Especially so here because your solution won't work. So not amount of help with it does any good solving your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed this is a very complex subject, you would need to work with a File System Filter Driver (https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/index) very low level stuff which would be hard to implement, I think that at least in the .net world there is not an easy way to do this.